# When I click on a user in the custom user model in admin, an error occurs (django)

Tags: django

step1
settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

step2
accounts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    # website = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False)
```

step3
1.delete db.sqlite3
2.migrations, migrate

```
(askcompany) C:\my_django\askcompany>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

(askcompany) C:\my_django\askcompany>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, blog1, contenttypes, instagram, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

step4
and When I click on a user in the custom user model in admin, an error occurs (django)

error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\hyunsepk\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\askcompany\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user_groups
[02/Aug/2020 15:41:10] "GET /admin/accounts/user/2/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 217698
```

[image]

[image]

how to fix it?

thanks for let me know

Answer (score 0):

look like you miss migrations

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I definitely ran the migration migrate, and I deleted db.sql3 and tried again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you havent migrated, and hence there is no such table in your database. So migrate it by `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`. And then try it.

Comment: I definitely ran the migration migrate, I deleted db.sql3 and tried again.

Comment: why did you delete your sqlite db? migrations can't run because there clearly no db file for your schemas/table to be written. try restoring the db.sqilite then apply migrations